# Regex To Match Fancy Quote

Tags: java, regex

Is there a way in regex to match all kinds of quotes?  I'm matching the `'` character but is there a way to change the below regex pattern to also match ```` ``` ```` and `` ` ``?

```
final Pattern QUOTE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("'''.*?'''|'.*?'", Pattern.DOTALL);
final Matcher quoteMatcher = ContentCommonConstants.QUOTE_PATTERN.matcher(value);
```

Comment: If you want to post \` then add backslash before it

Comment: @Sniffer - Pshemo updated it.  I don't think the \``` and \` are supported UTF-8 characters

Comment: The real unicode quotation marks (`“...”`) and those used in [other languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-English_usage_of_quotation_marks) as well?

Comment: @c12 I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. Do you want to include all quotation marks in your regex like mentioned in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark_glyphs, or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-English_usage_of_quotation_marks, or maybe only specific ones?

Comment: @Pshemo - no I want to basically search a string that may or may not contain html in between single or triple quotes. if it contains single or triple quotes I perform some processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why can't you do something like this:

````
'''.*?'''|'.*?'|```.*?```|\\u2018.*?\\u2019
````

**NOTICE:** `\u2018` is the Unicode code point of the single left quote `‘`.

`\u2019` is the Unicode code point of the single right quote `’`.

Comment: why is the unicode needed only for the single and not the triple quote?  Could you just use \` instead of \\u2018 ?

Comment: @c12 Because I can't type those characters with my keyboard so I just used there Unicode code point, if you want you can put them in directly and I think it will work. On the other hand, `\`` is present on my keyboard and I could type it easily but pay attention that it is different from quoting characters.